# Android Custom Multidex Application Error

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I'm trying to create an Android Application Class that extends MultidexApplication.

```java
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        registerParseSubClasses();
        parseInit();
    }

    private void registerParseSubClasses() {
        //registering subclasses
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(UserPlace.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(PlaceItem.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(PlaceItemRating.class);
    }
    private void parseInit() {
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getBaseContext())
            .applicationId("MYAPPID")
            .server("MyURL")
            //.enableLocalDataStore()
            .build());
        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

And my Android Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pnametala.application" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

and here's my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pnametala.application"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        jackOptions {
          enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
}
```

If i use MultidexApplication in My AndroidManifest.xml, it works like a charm but I need to input some init overrides that can't be done without that.

The stack trace is:

> Unable to instantiate application com.pnametala.application.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pnametala.application.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pnametala.application-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.pnametala.application-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: add MultiDex.install(this); in your MyApplication class, it should have one. maybe that's why you got an error

Comment: @masoudvali There is `MultiDex.install(this);` in `MultiDexApplication.attachBaseContext()` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/multidex/+/master/library/src/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.java#39

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what resolved the question was split the google-play-service lib in parts, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

I just import the libs that I realy need to use (like maps and adress api).

For now, I'm not using Multidex anymore.